# Powershell for protecting particular cell

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to protect particular cell of excel while generating excel file from powershell. I have already tried some option but I could found option to make whole sheet as readonly but not particular cell.

How do I do it?

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to lock the cells

```
$Excel.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B2").Locked = $True
```

Then to protect the whole workbook.

Comment: After my operation I am using below logic..But it is not working

$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Kunal1\DiskSpace.xlsx")


$workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Range("A1:A6").Locked = $True

$excel.Quit()

Set-ItemProperty -Path "C:\Kunal1\DiskSpace.xlsx" -Name IsReadOnly -value $True

$workbook.Save

Comment: You should to protect the workbook in Excel, not the file from the file system.

Comment: You should save the workbook before you quit excel, right? `$workbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Range("A1:A6").Locked = $True; 
 $workbook.Save; $excel.Quit(); `